# Check only existing first Numeric value

Tags: ios, swift, higher-order-functions

I am performing filter and that filter options contain **numeric** and **string**. If the user clicks on **#** then it will display all prefix numeric values.

```
let filterValue = ["3D Amazon", "ABC", "5G", "Flip 3Te"]
```

The output will look like **3D Amazon** and **5G**

Comment: Almost literal English: `.filter{$0.first?.isNumber == true}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display all prefix numeric values:

```
print(filterValue.filter{$0.first?.isNumber == true})
```

**Output:**

```
["3D Amazon", "5G"]
```

Comment: This answer is decent, but not perfect. It will miss strings like "-3", which is arguably a numeric value.